# Hardware Super High Res Video Decoding and Rendreing on OpenGL/DirectX

Tags: opengl, directx, gpu, directshow, video-processing

I am trying to decode and render super high res videos (4k x 4k) and the videos are encoded with h.264 codec. While decoding the video frames, we would like to render the frames on shaders, currently in opengl pipeline with glsl, so that we can manipulate the fragment colors on the fly. We have tested using FFmpeg decoding APIs, but the bottleneck lies on the software decoding time and data transferring at the following gl function call:

```
glTexSubImage2D(...);
```

We've considered using DirectShow to decode video frames by utilizing HW acceleration on GPUs and use NV_DX_interop2 to map GL's texture slot to the decoded memory address, but the current max resolution for decoding h.264 frames is 1920x1080, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390679(v=vs.85).aspx).

So I guess my question is: Is there any suggestion for decoding super high res videos (presuming in h.264 codec) by utilizing HW acceleration, mapping the GPU's video memory address and rendering it as a texture?

Answer (score 2):

[Map a PBO](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html#map) and decode/swscale directly into the buffer.  After you unmap the `glTexSubImage2D()` becomes a GPU->GPU operation and nearly "free".

With shaders you can render YUV directly and avoid using swscale for a YUV->RGB conversion, saving more CPU time for decode.